# Invalid certification path - tomcat, SSL, Jasig

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, jasig

I try to login into cas-management-app using cas-server-webapp and I have problems with certification path.

I generated keystore file:

```
"$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool.exe" -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
Enter keystore password:  pass
Re-enter new password: pass
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  localhost
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  localhost
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  localhost
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:  Crc
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  Lesser
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  PL
Is CN=localhost, OU=localhost, O=localhost, L=Crc, ST=Lesser, C=PL correct?
  [no]:  yes

Enter key password for <tomcat>
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):  pass
Re-enter new password: pass
```

I changed Tomcat configuration:
server.xml

```
<Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="C:/Users/Mateusz/.keystore" keystorePass="pass"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Value of *keystoreFile* is valid path.

In next step I exported (using browser) certificate to localhost.crt and added it to cacerts:

```
 "$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool.exe" -import -alias incommon -file <localhost.crt location> -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit
```

When I list cacerts everything is OK:

```
$ "$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool.exe" -v -list -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: incommon
Creation date: 2015-11-02
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=localhost, OU=localhost, O=localhost, L=Crc, ST=Lesser, C=PL
Issuer: CN=localhost, OU=localhost, O=localhost, L=Crc, ST=Lesser, C=PL
Serial number: 32432ba5
Valid from: Mon Nov 02 19:19:02 CET 2015 until: Sun Jan 31 19:19:02 CET 2016
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  9F:A6:4A:B0:F3:26:89:60:73:5C:CA:36:59:0A:32:F9
         SHA1: 62:12:60:61:A9:3D:83:E8:1B:C5:3A:85:27:9A:7F:A7:D3:54:7D:D1
         SHA256: F1:43:EE:6E:F7:D4:C6:DF:20:16:71:C1:0D:F5:88:5F:85:21:BE:E6:3C:E5:C1:8D:28:6A:51:BB:38:E7:A2:94
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: B0 94 2A 98 B8 A4 21 71   EB 34 46 D4 16 67 24 E8  ..*...!q.4F..g$.
0010: 67 61 C4 D6                                        ga..
]
]
```

When I run Tomcat server, open https://localhost:8443/cas-management I can see login form. After writing user login and password I see message:

```
The CAS management webapp is unavailable.
There was an error trying to complete your request. Please notify your support desk or try again.
```

Log files give me information

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/cas-management] threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I tried to install certs using InstallCert class but nothing changed. I also tried setup path to trust store (jssecacerts) using truststoreFile and truststorePass in Tomcat configuration.

I have no idea what next I can do to successfully configure SSL on my Tomcat server.

Comment: Solved. Problem was caused by XAMPP - `[XAMPP] Set JAVA_HOME:`.